How to use custom labels in LWC that is used in standalone LWR SPA NodeJS module?
I am trying to create LWR SPA project that consisted by LWCs.
I have created new LWR SPA with command : "npm init lwr@latest"
The steps was

set project name - lwr-project.
Select Type - Single Page Application (SPA)
Select Component - LWC

Then, I created SFDX project under the LWR SPA project with name lwc-backend.
I have followed all the steps to use Basic Salesforce Lightning Design System which is referred at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-slds.html,
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-lwc.html

in the LWR SPA project.
When I created new LWC component in the SFDX project, and config lwr.config.json in the LWR SPA project to refer the LWC component, the LWC is shown correctly in LWR SPA.
I have retrieved the customLabel and Translations by running "sf project retrieve start -m CustomLabels" and "sf project retrieve start -m Translations".
Under the lwc-backend/force-app/main/default, two directories are created with "labels" and "translations" with file "CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml", and "en_US.translation-meta.xml" in each directory.
Then I was going to use the customLabels and Translations in the LWC component, but there is an error message: LwrUnresolvableError [DiagnosticsError]: 404: Could not find module entry with specifier "@salesforce/label/c.TestCustomLabel".
This is the code to retrieve CustomLabel in the Component
// test.js
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import testCustomLabel from "@salesforce/label/c.TestCustomLabel";

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
  label = { testCustomLabel };
}

// test.html
<template>
  <div>{label.testCustomLabel}</div>
</template>

And this codes are in LWR SPA to call the LWC component:
// app.html
<template>
  <div>
    <lwc-test-component></lwc-test-component>
  </div>
</template>

// lwr.config.json
{
  "lwc": {
    "modules": [
      {
        "name": "lwc/test",
        "path": "$rootDir/lwc-backend/force-app/main/default/lwc/test/test.js
      },
    ...
    ]
  },
  ...
}

If I do not use custom label or other APIs, it shows all contents with css.
Also, if I deploy the LWC component into the Salesforce org, the custom label is shown well in Lightning App Builder of Salesforce.
However, I want to use the LWC components in the LWR SPA NodeJS project in local with Visual Studio Code.
Ultimately, not only the @salesforce/label, also I want to use @salesforce/apex classes as well in the LWC component.

Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I've linked a question that I wrote last year that describes how to get @salesforce/apex modules to resolve, but this also applies for anything else you'd want to add, including custom labels. Please let us know if this answer solves your problem, or if you need further assistance. We'll be happy to reopen your question if you're unable to get the solution working.

@sfdcfox Hi, I saw the posted question before, but it does not contain how to use resources that I already created in Salesforce Org, instead it returns string type. In force-app/main/default, there is classes, label, and translations that are deployed on / retrieved by Salesforce org, and I want to use them in LWC, then use the LWC on LWR without deployment the LWC. Can I get some specific information to use them?

I'm not sure you'll get an answer, but I agree that this question seeks a different answer, and that answer would definitely be useful.
